# Return only rows whose max value is less than specified

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, max

Hi this is quite a tricky one (for me). I have three tables.

One contains mobile numbers and a unique id (tbldealermobiles)

```
FCS - Mobile number
1234 - 07464648787
1234 - 07565465465
3566 - 07878989989
7899 - 07464646466
7899 - 07565465464
9654 - 07589898998
```

One contains purchase dates and a unique id and other details (tblhistory)

```
FCS - purchase date - purchased
1234 - 22/04/2013 - gloves
1234 - 14/03/2013 - hat
1234 - 01/03/2013 - coat
3566 - 20/04/2013 - gloves
3566 - 19/04/2012 - hat
7899 - 14/03/2013 - shoes
9654 - 24/05/2013 - hat
9654 - 19/04/2013 - shoes
```

One contains customer type and a unique id and other details. (tblAllDealers)

```
FCS - Cust type - name
1234 - Virtual - Jim
3566 - Outbound - Jon
7899 - Virtual - Jack
9654 - Outbound - Susan
```

My problem comes when I want to display customers who have bought more than 30 days ago if they're 'Outbound' and more than 60 days ago if they're virtual.

I only want to return all the mobile numbers for Jon and Jack because the others have purchased since the dates specified for their customer type.

I'm using INNER JOIN to link the 3 tables on the unique id(FCS), I'm using MAX to return only values who's MAX value is less than a date but I have no clue how to add criteria to specify two different dates.

Here is the query I have so far -

```
SELECT *
FROM tbldealermobiles
  INNER JOIN tblhistory ON tbldealermobiles.FCS = tblhistory.FCS
  INNER JOIN tblAllDealers ON tbldealermobiles.FCS = tblAllDealers.FCS
WHERE (tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Virtual' AND
       tblhistory.PurchaseDate < date('2013-03-22'))
    OR 
      (tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Outbound' AND 
       tblhistory.PurchaseDate < date('2013-04-21')) 
GROUP BY tbldealermobiles.mobilenumber 
HAVING MAX(tblhistory.PurchaseDate) < date('2013-04-21') 
ORDER BY tblhistory.PurchaseDate DESC
```

The problem is that the FCS will probably always have a purchase date earlier than the date specified but I only want to return a mobile number that hasn't got a purchase date after the date specified depending on customer group.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: thanks for formatting my code Dukeling.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: MySQL 5.5.27 - I'm guessing thats what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pull the condition from the join into a `having` clause.  The join is *only* looking at records before those dates, so you don't know if anything happens afterwards.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbldealermobiles
  INNER JOIN tblhistory ON tbldealermobiles.FCS = tblhistory.FCS
  INNER JOIN tblAllDealers ON tbldealermobiles.FCS = tblAllDealers.FCS
WHERE tblAllDealers.CustGroup in ('Virtual', 'Outbound')
GROUP BY tbldealermobiles.mobilenumber 
HAVING MAX(tblhistory.PurchaseDate) <
            MAX(case when tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Virtual' then date('2013-03-22')
                     when tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Outbound' then date('2013-04-21')
                end)
ORDER BY tblhistory.PurchaseDate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon - that makes a lot more sense but when I run that query I'm getting all 'Virtual' and 'Outbound' customers regardless of what date they purchased on. Edit: Sorry I realised you've put '>=' if I turn it round I get what I'm after...sorry for doubting you :D

Comment: Hi Gordon - if I put '>' i get dates before the dates specified ? Can this query be modified for dates after the date specified?

Comment: @ch3my . . . I'm not sure what logic you want.  What is there is that the maximum date is always less than one of the two date values.  If you want dates after that period, you can remove the `having`.  If you want customers all of whose purchases are after those dates, then change the `max()` to a `min()`.  And so on.

Comment: I would like to only show customers who have bought since those dates but they may have also bought before them - but I don't want to show customers who haven't bought since. Basically i'm trying to pull recent buyers depending on their customer group.

Comment: I've gone with 
`WHERE (tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Outbound' and tblhistory.purchasedate > date('2013-04-21') and tblhistory.make='Nike' and tblhistory.range='Hats') OR (tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Virtual' and tblhistory.purchasedate > date('2013-03-21') and tblhistory.make='Nike' and tblhistory.range='Hats')` Is there a better way to write that ?