# Return only rows whose max value is greater than specified

Tags: mysql, sql, max

Hi I asked a question here: [Return only rows whose max value is less than specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671565/return-only-rows-whose-max-value-is-less-than-specified)

The answer I got was perfect for what I wanted :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbldealermobiles
  INNER JOIN tblhistory ON tbldealermobiles.FCS = tblhistory.FCS
  INNER JOIN tblAllDealers ON tbldealermobiles.FCS = tblAllDealers.FCS
WHERE tblAllDealers.CustGroup in ('Virtual', 'Outbound')
GROUP BY tbldealermobiles.mobilenumber 
HAVING MAX(tblhistory.PurchaseDate) <
        MAX(case when tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Virtual' then date('2013-03-22')
                 when tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Outbound' then date('2013-04-21')
            end)
ORDER BY tblhistory.PurchaseDate DESC
```

I'm trying to re-purpose it by simply changing the less than symbol to a greater than symbol like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbldealermobiles
  INNER JOIN tblhistory ON tbldealermobiles.FCS = tblhistory.FCS
  INNER JOIN tblAllDealers ON tbldealermobiles.FCS = tblAllDealers.FCS
WHERE tblAllDealers.CustGroup in ('Virtual', 'Outbound')
GROUP BY tbldealermobiles.mobilenumber 
HAVING MAX(tblhistory.PurchaseDate) >
        MAX(case when tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Virtual' then date('2013-03-22')
                 when tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Outbound' then date('2013-04-21')
            end)
ORDER BY tblhistory.PurchaseDate DESC
```

But I get mobile numbers out that are before the dates specified, can this query be used like this or do I need to re-write it?

Output :

I get 795 rows and here are the last 15 :

```
PurchaseDate CustGroup
2012-05-12  Outbound
2012-05-12  Outbound
2012-05-11  Virtual
2012-05-10  Virtual
2012-05-10  Outbound
2012-05-10  Outbound
2012-05-10  Virtual
2012-05-10  Outbound
2012-05-10  Outbound
2012-05-10  Virtual
2012-05-09  Outbound
2012-05-09  Outbound
2012-05-09  Outbound
2012-05-08  Outbound
2012-05-08  Outbound
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a sample output ?

Comment: Please show some of the dates that are returned.

Comment: Edited post with output - thanks

Comment: the `PurchaseDate` from the sample is the column from `tblhistory` table?

Comment: Yes - only tblhistory has PurchaseDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done your ORIGINAL query like this..

```
select *
FROM tbldealermobiles m
INNER JOIN tblhistory h ON m.FCS = h.FCS
INNER JOIN tblAllDealers a ON m.FCS = a.FCS
WHERE a.CustGroup in ('Virtual', 'Outbound')
and h.PurchaseDate = (
    select max(h2.PurchaseDate) from tblhistory h2
    where h2.fcs = a.fcs)
and (a.CustGroup = 'Virtual' AND
     h.PurchaseDate < date('2013-03-22')
  or 
    a.CustGroup = 'Outbound' AND 
    h.PurchaseDate < date('2013-04-21'))
ORDER BY h.PurchaseDate DESC
```

Then, for this query, just change the `<` symbols to `>`.

Comment: Hi - that takes a while to fire, not sure why but it just times out.

Comment: What indexes are on those columns? It shouldn't time out. Make sure you have indexes on FCS, CustGroup and PurchaseDate (if you can).

Answer (score 0):

@ch3my- I may be missing something here, but what about adding **AND PurchaseDate >= '2013-05-01'** to your WHERE clause (setting the date to the minimum date you were looking for)

Comment: I need different dates for the different customer groups ie `if 'Outbound' then PurchaseDate >= '2013-04-21' OR if 'Virtual' then PurchaseDate >= '2013-03-22'` But in query format :) I'm testing whether this would work or not `WHERE (tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Outbound' and tblhistory.purchasedate > date('2013-04-21') and tblhistory.make='Nike' and tblhistory.range='Hats') OR (tblAllDealers.CustGroup = 'Virtual' and tblhistory.purchasedate > date('2013-03-21') and tblhistory.make='Nike' and tblhistory.range='Hats')` Is there a better way to write that? I've two more criteria :)